# Page not behaving responsive when accessed through domain name

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, azure, dns

I have been working on a responsive site using bootstrap and hosted on Azure. This was working fine and still is working fine in all tests on mobiles, when accessed directly at 
REMOVEDLINK however after I had our domain name go live (which was taken care of by an outsourced IT department), when we try and access the site using the new address it fails to be responsive and mobile friendly. REMOVEDLINK (works ok in browser, when physically resizing but using something like browserstack shows issues that are apparent on mobiles).

My first thought was maybe the libraries were not being referenced properly, but I can see no issue there. Any guidance would be much appreciated, is there perhaps a value that needs to be added when domain name is made live ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your outsourced department did is they put your website into HTML `frame` element.
You have to change settings of your domain (www.shoppixapp.com).

[Click here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean) to see tutorial on configuring domains in Digital Ocean but you will get the idea what is going on (or send it to the guys that are responsible for it).

Right now all your domain is doing is loading page -> loading frame with content of external server (morpheus-frontend) and this is why it is not responsive. (And also you won't be able to use (for example) facebook login on shoppixapp domain)

Comment: thank you, that helps immensely